# How to convert curl to Ruby Net::HTTP with -X GET -G options?

Tags: ruby, http, curl

I was using https://jhawthorn.github.io/curl-to-ruby/ to convert curl commands to Net::HTTP code.  However the following cannot be converted using the jhawthorn resource:

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token token=$PAGERDUTY_ACCESS_KEY" -X GET -G --data-urlencode "since=2017-01-16" --data-urlencode "until=2017-01-17"  "https://company.pagerduty.com/api/v1/schedules"
```

I have described my exact problem in this github issue: https://github.com/jhawthorn/curl-to-ruby/issues/8

This is my current function that uses the Net::HTTP gem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'json'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

def get_pagerduty_hash(ending='')
  uri = URI.parse("https://company.pagerduty.com/api/v1/schedules#{ending}")
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
  request.content_type = "application/json"
  request["Authorization"] = "Token token=#{ENV['PAGERDUTY_ACCESS_KEY']}"

  req_options = {
    use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
  }

  response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
    http.request(request)
  end

  return JSON.parse(response.body).to_hash 

end
```

How can I change this to correctly use the date part of the original curl command:

```
-X GET -G --data-urlencode "since=2017-01-16" --data-urlencode "until=2017-01-17"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `URI.encode_www_form` function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'json'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

def get_pagerduty_hash(ending='')
  uri = URI.parse("https://company.pagerduty.com/api/v1/schedules#{ending}")
  params = { :since => '2017-01-16', :until => '2017-01-17' }
  uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
  request.content_type = "application/json"
  request["Authorization"] = "Token token=#{ENV['PAGERDUTY_ACCESS_KEY']}"

  req_options = {
    use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
  }

  response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
    http.request(request)
  end

  return JSON.parse(response.body).to_hash 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

`urlencode` means that the data is encoded in the URL

```
url = URI.parse('http://example.com')
url.query = "since=2017-01-16&until=2017-01-17"
puts url
# => http://example.com?since=2017-01-16&until=2017-01-17
```